# Why is my 'old_items_list' equals to 'items_list'?

Tags: python, html

```
def scraping():
    old_items_list = items_list
    x = 0
    for item in items:
        item_price = item.find("span", {"class": "price-text-E1Y7h text-text-LurtD text-size-s-BxGpL"})
        item_url_container = item.find("div", {"class": "iva-item-titleStep-_CxvN"})
        item_url = item_url_container.a["href"]
        item_name_container = item.find("h3", {"class": "title-root-j7cja iva-item-title-_qCwt title-listRedesign-XHq38 title-root_maxHeight-SXHes text-text-LurtD text-size-s-BxGpL text-bold-SinUO"})
        item_name = item_name_container.text

        items_list[x] = item_url
        x += 1
    print(items_list)
    if items_list == old_items_list:
        return True
    if items_list != old_items_list:
        print('found difference')
        new_items_list = list(set(old_items_list).difference(items_list))
        print(new_items_list)
        for item in new_items_list:
            print(item)



items_list = [1,2,3]
while True:
    scraping()
    print('HUH??')

    sleep(3)
```

I'm confused why code is shown this way, but I hope it's readable. I don't mention old_items_list anywhere except the beginning of the function, but it still changes its properties as the function progresses

Comment: Stackoverflow markdown requires 4 spaces to start a code block. That means if you want to indent 4 spaces, you need to indent 8 spaces in the editor. Go back and start adding 4 spaces to those lines you want indented and you see that they start looking right in the rendered code.

Comment: You got a lot of code there when really you just care about the list update for this question. Can you simplfy? I see `old_items_list = items_list` - that doesn't copy list. It only means that those two variables reference the same list.

Comment: `old_items_list = items_list.copy()` should do the trick. As @tdelaney has pointed out, both the variables are referencing the same list.

Comment: Thank you everybody!!! Solved. Do I need to delete the post?

Comment: Does molshape answer your question? If so, accept that instead of deleting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`old_items_list = items_list` is creating a reference to `items_list`. You are looking for something like this:

```py
original_list = [1, 2, 3]
reference_list = original_list
old_list = original_list.copy()

print(original_list)
original_list.append(4)
print(reference_list)
print(old_list)  # this is what you are looking for
```

Use the `.copy()` method on your list in order to create a copy of your original list.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In most common languages, when you assign variables, you are assigning references where the value of that variable is pointing at (for example memory pointers in C or java heap space references).

So, you can imagine the sentence "old_items_list = items_list" just like:

1. memory_reference has the value [x,y,z]
2. items_list is pointing to memory_reference so the value is the value linked to the memory_reference (as we said before [x,y,z])
3. old_items_list is pointing to items_list so both variables are pointing to the same values reference, so we are referencing the same instances

In order to not have the same references, you can:

1. Perform a copy for each element or in the list if the variables are inmutable
2. Serialize the list and deserialize it again in the new variable to have the same values pointing to different places.